# How common stock equity related to number of share outstanding?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, shares, balance-sheet

Recently, I check Facebook information about shares as below:
[Facebook balance sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRwVV.png)

According to the definition, the common stock equation is represented as :
Number of Outstanding Shares = Number of Issued Shares – Treasury Stocks

But why on the Facebook balance sheet, the number of issued shares fluctuated very small while common stock equity has high volatility? How common stock equity is determined? is it included the stocks owned by the public?

Comment: Is this balance sheet from Yahoo Finance?

Answer (score 0):

Common stock equity is the *value* of those shares. The number of shares outstanding typically doesn't change very much. It is only affected by new issuances (rare), buybacks (slightly less rare) and stock compensation awards (common but relatively small).

The *value* of those shares however, changes as the company makes money (among other things). Obviously a profitable company like Facebook (at least now) can have very large changes in equity without changing the number of outstanding shares significantly.

Also note that the number you cite is the *book* value of the equity of Facebook - it is very different that the *market* value of that equity, which is determined by the market price of Facebook stock.

Comment: if it's the book value of the equity of Facebook, how come it changes? I thought only market value changes, the book value is fixed over time. If possible, could you give some example of what factors make the book value increase/decrease?  I'm really confused about that.

Comment: You may be thinking of _par_ value. Book value of equity is assets minus liabilities (plus a few other adjustments) and changes as a company earns a profit (or a loss). If I have a company that's worth $100, and it makes $10 in profit, the company is now worth $110.